# Is there a workaround for this chrome bug with vertical flex box and dynamically removing elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

If you have a look at this code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inner-content").text("test ".repeat(5000));
});

function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content{
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}



.footer{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```

I have a vertical flexbox, with a set-height header & footer. Plus a body that fills the space and scrolls if it overflows.

If I dynamically remove or hide the footer (by clicking the button on the codepen), the body content will not render where the footer used to be. This only seems to happen in chrome.

Is there a workaround / fix for this?

[How it appears in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzN1s.png)

[How it should appear (firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2SsH.png)

Comment: Firefox same behavior.

Comment: @kmgt Firefox is working for me - version 65.0.1

Comment: Firefox 68.0.2 (64-Bit)

Comment: I see no bug with google chrome , latest version

Comment: @G-Cyr I am also on latest version (I think) - version 76.0.3809.100

Comment: @G-Cyr having the issue on windows

Comment: @TemaniAfif ?? strange, i do not , either from the snippet, jsfiddle  or codepen

Comment: It seems to be a rendering bug in Chrome. If you resize after clicking it will show correctly.

Comment: here is what i have *chrome is on the left* https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awt1I.jpg

Comment: @G-Cyr you are also getting the error. You can see that the text does not go all the way to the bottom. If you resize your chrome window it will re-render and show more text. It's more obvious if you increase the height of the footer. Chrome only seems to render text where the top pixel is above where the footer used to be

Comment: okay, for a redraw you can also do `function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
  $(".content").css('position','relative')
}` and i'll buy myself a new pair of glasses ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr seems to be a good workaround.

Comment: Has there been a Chrome bug logged for this? Is it being tracked anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` + `z-index` from the CSS, after all, might do without to be triggered on hidding the footer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inner-content").text("test ".repeat(5000));
});

function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content{
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  /* chrome*/
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}



.footer{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```

or the classic : backface-visibility:hidden

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inner-content").text("test ".repeat(5000));
});

function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content{
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
  /* chrome*/
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}



.footer{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to force a redraw of the content. You can do this using a show/hide like below. You can notice that a browser resizing will fix the issue since it will also redraw the content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inner-content").text("test ".repeat(5000));
});

function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
  $('.content').hide().show(0);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.content{
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}



.footer{
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution, unfortunately in my real app I am using angular so would rather avoid manually writing calls to hide/show if possible

Comment: @Jacob will try to find another way but at least you know that a fix is to force a redraw to avoid this bug. There is many ways to do this.

Comment: you can update position or transform too : `function test(){
  $(".footer").remove();
  $(".content").css('position','relative')
}` for a redraw , creating a pseudo element on the fly works too if that is to cure the bug